# Minetest Server Can't Be Reached From WAN, but Minecraft Can

Tags: linux, server-administration, minetest

I'm trying to run a Minetest server that people can connect to. If I run a Minecraft server with my ports open, I can see port 25565 at [canyouseeme.org](https://canyouseeme.org/). When I run a Minetest server with the same port, I can't see it on canyouseeme.org.

I have both UDP and TCP enabled on port forwarding. I can join my Minetest server if I use my local IP (`192.168.1.135:25565`) instead of my public one (`xx.xxx.xx.xx:25565`).

When Minecraft is running, and I use `sudo ss -tupln`, I can see:

```
Netid      State       Recv-Q      Send-Q           Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port     Process                                                                                                                                                                   
tcp        LISTEN      0           4096                         *:25565                      *:*         users:(("java",pid=6923,fd=146))
```

When MineTest is running, I can see:

```
Netid             State              Recv-Q             Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port            Process                                           
udp               UNCONN             0                  0                                    0.0.0.0:25565                              0.0.0.0:*                users:(("minetest",pid=8710,fd=4))
```

I've tried running the Minetest server both from the game, from Docker image (used port `30000`), and command line. When running from command line, I use `minetest --server --terminal` from inside my `~/.minetest` folder (`minetest` is installed from Arch repos), and I've got the following in my `~/.minetest/minetest.conf`:

```
name=duck
server_announce=true
server_name=Hello
server_description=HelloDesc
port=25565
```

I've also tried other ports, but no results. I was using `25565` because it worked for Minecraft, but it's not working for Minetest.

I can see my server hosted on [servers.minetest.net](http://servers.minetest.net/) and I can find it in the server list, but if I try to join, it says "Connection timed out"

Answer (score 1):

Minetest is weird. If I run from the command line `minetest --server --terminal`, it publishes my server to http://servers.minetest.net/. *I* have to join my server via 0.0.0.0:25565 (because that's the port I specified in my `minetest.conf`), but my friends join via `xx.xxx.xxx.xx:25565` (my IP). They can also search for my server name in the Minetest Server list